Reducing white/empty space from the right of the page
How can I remove the right space in this page?
And how can I increase the size of the table to be fit with the text?
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)

\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{bibentry} 

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{stix,bbding,pifont,utfsym,fontawesome}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees} 
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\usepackage{tabu, colortbl}

% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
 \journalname{The Journal of }

%
\begin{document}


Today’s HPC applications are producing extremely large amounts of data, thus it is necessary to use an efficient compression before storing them to parallel file systems. In this paper, we optimize the error-bounded HPC data compression, by proposing a novel HPC data compression method that works very effectively on compressing large-scale HPC data sets. The compression method starts by linearizing multi-dimensional snapshot data. The key idea is to fit/predict the successive data points with the bestfit selection of curve fitting models. The data that can be predicted precisely will be replaced by the code of the corresponding curve-fitting model. 

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Different types of datasets . }
\label{tabadf}
%\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
%\small
\scalebox{0.5}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|cccccc|c|c|}
\hline
Dataset               & Data type & Dataset  &  test   & P\_value  & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Critial }                                                                                                                              & Result:        & Comp. ratio \\ \hline
A                     & Int 32    & 2000         & 067 & $1.04\times 10^{-10}$  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-3.437} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-2.864} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{10\%} & -2.568  & ss     & 1669.3662       \\ \hline
B                     & Int 32    & 7000         & 304 & $3.94\times 10^{-13}$  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-3.437} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-2.864} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{10\%} & -2.568 & ss     & 168.168       \\ \hline
C                     & Int 32    & 5000         & -8.546 & $9.50\times 10^{-14}$  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-3.437} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-2.864} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{10\%} & -2.568 & ss     & 165.165       \\ \hline
D                     & Int 32    & 4000         & -2.659 & 0.081 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-3.437} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-2.864} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{10\%} & -2.568 & Non ss & 1663.41       \\ \hline
E                     & Int 32    & 300         & -2.307 & 0.170  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-3.438} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-2.865} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{10\%} & -2.568 & Non ss & 1.6       \\ \hline

\end{tabular}}
%\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}



%\bibliography{template}

\end{document}
% end of file template.tex


\usepackage{geometry} to adjust your margins.
Never adjustbox or scalebox a table.  It makes it impossible for the content of the table to have sizing consistent with the rest of your document.  Taking that our, your question becomes "how can I decrease the size of the table to be fit with the text?".
As a general guideline, if the same value shows up in every column, it doesn't really need to be in the table.  I've moved "Int 32" to the table's caption, guessed that 1%, 5%, and 10% were supposed to describe the subsequent column, and left that the subsequent columns alone on the assumption that the numbers are actually supposed to be different.
We can get a bit more space by combining the two now adjacent Dataset column headers into one, and changing "Result:" into "ss?" with a "y/n" entry.  This is still a bit wider than article's defaults, but maybe your documentclass (which isn't a default) has a different size (and you're planning on changing the margins anyway).
I've also used booktabs to create the lines in the table, and deleted the vertical lines because they don't help understand the data.  And \begin{table}[] causes a warning: either remove the [], or put in some of the options [tbhp] (the more the better).
You could also look at using siunitx to format your numbers as S columns.  Are the dataset numbers sizes or model numbers?  What's going on with the "test" column?  Do you really have 8 significant figures with the first comp. ratio?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\begin{document}

Today’s HPC applications are producing extremely large amounts of data, thus it is necessary to use an efficient compression before storing them to parallel file systems. In this paper, we optimize the error-bounded HPC data compression, by proposing a novel HPC data compression method that works very effectively on compressing large-scale HPC data sets. The compression method starts by linearizing multi-dimensional snapshot data. The key idea is to fit/predict the successive data points with the bestfit selection of curve fitting models. The data that can be predicted precisely will be replaced by the code of the corresponding curve-fitting model. 

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Different types of datasets with data type Int 32. }
\label{tabadf}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Dataset}  &  test   & P\_value  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Critical} & ss? & Comp. \\\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
&&&& 1\% & 5\% & 10\% && ratio \\\midrule
A & 2000 & 067 & $1.04\times 10^{-10}$  & -3.437 & -2.864 & -2.568  & y     & 1669.3662 \\
B & 7000 & 304 & $3.94\times 10^{-13}$  & -3.437 & -2.864 & -2.568 & y     & 168.168 \\
C & 5000 & -8.546 & $9.50\times 10^{-14}$  & -3.437 & -2.864 & -2.568 & y     & 165.165 \\
D & 4000 & -2.659 & 0.081 & -3.437 & -2.864 & -2.568 & n & 1663.41 \\
E & 300 & -2.307 & 0.170  & -3.438 & -2.865 & -2.568 & n & 1.6 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}



The svjour3 class uses eight-point type for tables. Scaling the table is out of question, because it will use an unreadable size.
The output seems decent with the following code:
%\RequirePackage{fix-cm}% <--- unneeded because of stix

\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e} % <--- either this or algpseudocode
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <--- no longer needed
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[center]{caption} % <--- not with svjour3
\usepackage{bibentry} 

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{stix,bbding,pifont,utfsym,fontawesome}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} % <--- the option is necessary
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees} 
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx}

\usepackage{siunitx} % <--- added

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

%%%%\usepackage{tabu, colortbl} %%%% NO! tabu is deprecated

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
\linespread{1.05}


% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
 \journalname{The Journal of }

\begin{document}


Today’s HPC applications are producing extremely large amounts of data, 
thus it is necessary to use an efficient compression before storing them 
to parallel file systems. In this paper, we optimize the error-bounded HPC 
data compression, by proposing a novel HPC data compression method that 
works very effectively on compressing large-scale HPC data sets. 
The compression method starts by linearizing multi-dimensional 
snapshot data. The key idea is to fit/predict the successive data 
points with the bestfit selection of curve fitting models. The data 
that can be predicted precisely will be replaced by the code of the 
corresponding curve-fitting model. 

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{Different types of datasets}
\label{tabadf}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  c
  c
  S[table-format=4.0]
  S[table-format=-1.3]
  S[table-format=1.2e-2]
  c
  S[table-format=-1.3]
  c
  S[table-format=-1.3]
  c
  S[table-format=-1.3]
  c
  S[table-format=4.4]
}
\toprule
DS & DT & {DS}  &  {test}   & {P\_value}
 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Critical}  & Result   & {Comp.\ ratio} \\
\cmidrule{1-1}
\cmidrule{2-2}
\cmidrule{3-3}
\cmidrule{4-4}
\cmidrule{5-5}
\cmidrule{6-11}
\cmidrule{12-12}
\cmidrule{13-13}
A & Int 32 & 2000 & {067}  & 1.04e-10 & 1\% & -3.437 & 5\% & -2.864 & 10\% & -2.568 & ss     & 1669.3662       \\ 
B & Int 32 & 7000 & {304}  & 3.94e-13 & 1\% & -3.437 & 5\% & -2.864 & 10\% & -2.568 & ss     & 168.168       \\ 
C & Int 32 & 5000 & -8.546 & 9.50e-14 & 1\% & -3.437 & 5\% & -2.864 & 10\% & -2.568 & ss     & 165.165       \\ 
D & Int 32 & 4000 & -2.659 & {0.081}  & 1\% & -3.437 & 5\% & -2.864 & 10\% & -2.568 & Non ss & 1663.41       \\ 
E & Int 32 &  300 & -2.307 & {0.170}  & 1\% & -3.438 & 5\% & -2.865 & 10\% & -2.568 & Non ss & 1.6       \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}



%\bibliography{template}

\end{document}
% end of file template.tex

Please, check the comments I added and how I reorganized the preamble.
The package tabu should never be loaded: it's buggy and unmaintained; colortbl is already loaded when you pass the option table to xcolor.
Note also that caption is not compatible with svjour3, as it would change the format of captions: if you're required to use that class, the copy-editors will be very annoyed and you even risk rejection.

You can explain the abbreviated headers in the caption or below the table.
